# where id = multiple artists

Tags: php, mysql

Any time there is an update within my music community (song comment, artist update, new song added, yadda yadda yadda), a new row is inserted in my "updates" table.  The row houses the artist id involved along with other information (what type of change, time and date, etc).

My users have a "favorite artists" section where they can do just that -- mark artists as their favorites.  As such, I'd like to create a new feature that shows the user the changes made to their various favorite artists.

How should I be doing this efficiently?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_updates 
WHERE artist_id = 1 
OR artist_id = 500 
OR artist_id = 60032
```

Keep in mind, a user could have 43,000 of our artists marked as a favorite.

Thoughts?

Comment: Note that you say `AND` but you really mean `OR`. An `artist_id` can't be both 1 **and** 500.

Comment: ah yes, thank you... was just thinking on the fly and overlooked that bit

Answer (score 5):

This depends on how your database is setup. If I had my way, I'd set it up with a table like so:

```
Table: user_favourite_artist

user_id  |  artist_id
---------------------
1        |  2
1        |  8
1        |  13
2        |  2
3        |  6
6        |  20
6        |  1
6        |  3
```

user_id and artist_id together would be a composite primary key. Each row specifies a user, by id, and an artist they have as a favourite, by id. A query like so:

```
SELECT artist_id FROM user_favourite_artist WHERE user_id = 1
```

Would give you the artist_id's 2, 8, and 13. This is a very simple query that will scale to your expectations.

On the reverse, when an artist is updated, you'd run this query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_favourite_artist WHERE artist_id = 2
```

And you would get the user_id's 1 and 2. This will tell you which users to notify. This query is also simple and will scale.

Comment: I'm actually doing the opposite.  User 1 hits the Favorite Updates area.  The page should display all the updates to User 1's favorite artists.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_updates 
WHERE artist_id IN(1, 500, 60032)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the marked artists in a secondary table, I would recomend rather using a join.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FORM table_updates tu INNER JOIN
table_marked_by_user tmbu ON tu.artist_id = tmbu.artist_id
WHERE tmbu.user_id = $user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server, you can use a nested select statement:

```
select * from table_updates where artist_id in 
  (select artist_id from favorites_table where user_id = 10)
```

If you don't mind doing dirty reads, you can speed it up with (nolock).

```
select * from table_updates (nolock) where artist_id in 
  (select artist_id from favorites_table (nolock) where user_id = 10)
```